# Having difficulty using SoapUITestCaseRunner in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, junit, soapui

Let's get straight to the point:

I'm from QTP/UFT background. My company is transitioning from UFT to Selenium.
We've got Ready API couple of months ago and now I have couple of test cases in ready api. When we run the entire regression suite, we'll have to run the soapui testcases as well as part of the regression suite and then continue the rest of the suite. So, technically this is the flow: run some test against web - then soapui tests - then continue with web and complete the regression test suite in Selenium.

I was trying to put pieces together here. I was trying to execute one of the testcases from soapui using SoapUITestCaseRunner class in selenium.
When I use Launch testRunner in soapui it works perfectly but when I try it in selenium I'm getting an error. See the screenshots.
I've provided two screenshots. One of them will show you the Failure Trace.
Another one will show the console.

I want to know couple of things:
1. Could you help figure out what's happening?
2. Is there a way to automate cmd through selenium so I can execute cmd codes?
3. can I somehow run the .bat file through selenium?

I had to download soapui-1.7.1.jar to get the SoapUITestCaseRunner. For some reason it wasn't available when I'd added all soapui jar files as external.

[image]
[image]

thanks,

Comment: I've got one solution. I was able to run the .bat file using Process Runtime. It runs the .bat file as expected. Any other suggestion is welcome. It might help other testers.

Comment: From the screen shot, you are using SoapUI's API to run the project, but not appears to be running any batch file. Isn't it?